# Multiple applications listening on the same UDP port: broadcast IP VS non-broadcast IP wrt which gets the message

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, network-programming, udp

Apps A and B are both listening to and sending from UDP port 1337 on the same computer.
App A was started first (so it bound to port 1337 first).

When they each send a message to 127.255.255.255:1337 or 255.255.255.255:1337, **both** apps A and B get the each others' messages, as well as their own echo.

When they each send a message to 127.0.0.1:1337 or 192.168.1.65:1337, a non-broadcast address, **only** A gets B's message and its own echo. B cannot even hear its own message. (192.168.1.65 is my computer's network IP where both apps are running)

If I stop app A, B can hear its own message. If I start A again, B can hear both messages and A can head nothing.

Why do messages get duplicated when sent to a broadcast IP, whereas they are distributed on a first-come-first-serve basis if they are sent to a non-broadcast address? Is there a why to get a consistent behavior (set some "always-duplicate" flag)?

Here is some C# code that demonstrates this:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var udp = new Udp("255.255.255.255", 1337);
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(udp.Receive());
            }
        });
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                udp.Send("(((1)))");
            }
        });
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class Udp
{
    private readonly UdpClient _sender;
    private readonly UdpClient _listener;

    public Udp(string address, int port)
    {
        _sender = new UdpClient(address, port);
        _listener = new UdpClient();

        _listener.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
        _listener.Client.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port));
    }

    public string Receive()
    {
        var _ = null as IPEndPoint;
        return $"{Encoding.Default.GetString(_listener.Receive(ref _))} from {_.Address}:{_.Port}";
    }

    public void Send(string message)
    {
        var dataAsBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
        _sender.Send(dataAsBytes, dataAsBytes.Length);
    }
}
```

You can run this app twice, change the number in `udp.Send("(((1)))")` to identify each. When you use `new Udp("255.255.255.255", 1337)` both instances can hear both messages, whereas using `new Udp("127.0.0.1", 1337)` causes the first instance only to be able to pick up messages. Thank you!

Comment: You can have only one connection with same three parameters:1) Source IP Address, Destination IP Address, Port Number. This applies for sending and receiving since they both use the same connection.  When a connection is made an event is register in the windows operating system for the port number.  When incoming messages are receive the event handler finds first registered event for a port and sends the message to that application.  When two applications are registered for the same event only one gets the event.  It is possible for broadcast messages to be received by 2 apps using a group.